# Cube keeps generating too much edges in Python using the Turtle module

Tags: python

I am creating a 3D game engine using Python and its turtle module. However, whenever I try rendering a cube, it generates too many edges for the cube. I was worried that it could cause performance issues, so here is the relevent code that i use to generate the vertices and edges:

```py
def generate_cube_vertices(center_x: int | float, center_y: int | float, size: int | float):
    half_size = size / 2
    vertices = [
        (center_x - half_size, center_y - half_size, -half_size),
        (center_x - half_size, center_y - half_size, half_size),
        (center_x - half_size, center_y + half_size, -half_size),
        (center_x - half_size, center_y + half_size, half_size),
        (center_x + half_size, center_y - half_size, -half_size),
        (center_x + half_size, center_y - half_size, half_size),
        (center_x + half_size, center_y + half_size, -half_size),
        (center_x + half_size, center_y + half_size, half_size)
    ]
    return vertices


def generate_edges(vertices: list):
    edges = set()
    num_vertices = len(vertices)
    for i in range(num_vertices):
        for j in range(i + 1, num_vertices):
            edge = (i, j)
            edges.add(edge)
    return list(edges)
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. I tried searching online, to no avail.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: With this code, during the first iteration, you will create an edge between the vertex 0 and all the other verticies, while in a cube, each vertex is linked with only 3 other vertices. Your function just does not work.

Comment: Do you want an `edge` to be the pair of indexes that identify the two vertices, or do you want edge to be a pair of 3d coordinates themselves?

Comment: Hello @JonSG, I want it the be the pair of indexes that identify the two vertices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because your logic for joining the vertices is incorrect. The edges of a cube don't join the `i`th vertex with all subsequent vertices. Based on what your `generate_cube_vertices` returns, you have the following cube

```
   3--------7
  /|       /|
 / |      / |
2--+-----6  |
|  |     |  |
|  1-----+--5
| /      | /
|/       |/
0--------4
```

Now, you can simply hard-code the vertices for each edge, without needing the `vertices` list:

```py
def generate_edges() -> list[tuple[int, int]]:
    return [
        (0, 1), (0, 4), (0, 2),
        (1, 3), (1, 5),
        (2, 3), (2, 6),
        (3, 7),
        (4, 5), (4, 6),
        (5, 7),
        (6, 7)
    ]
```

You can make this a little more general if you recognize that for a cube whose sides are aligned with the x, y, and z axes (such as the one you generate), two vertices are connected only if they share two out of three coordinates. Using this observation, you could iterate over each pair of coordinates and check for this condition:

```
def generate_edges(vertices: list[tuple[float, float, float]]) -> list[tuple[int, int]]:
    edges = []
    num_vertices = len(vertices)
    for i in range(num_vertices):
        vertex_i = vertices[i]
        for j in range(i+1, num_vertices):
            vertex_j = vertices[j]
            num_common_coordinates = sum(vi == vj 
                          for vi, vj in zip(vertex_i, vertex_j))
            if num_common_coordinates == 2:
                edges.append((i, j))

    return edges
```

When you run this, you get the same result as the hardcoded approach above:

```
>>> verts = generate_vertices(0, 0, 10)
... edges = generate_edges(verts)

>>> print(edges)
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 4), (1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 7)]
```

Comment: Great ascii cube!

Comment: @JonSG Thanks, haha I spent more time on the ascii cube than I did on the rest of the answer ;)